# Three.js SkinnedMesh jitter when far from scene root (0,0,0) on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js

I'm working on a 3rd person RPG style game using Three.js and Blender. The world terrain is tiled and endlessly loops in all directions, getting triggered when the player obj nears an edge defined along z or x. I'm using the FBX importer, and things work fine on most platforms.

On IOS devices when I move the player object any significant distance from the scene root, the surface materials start to jitter and break apart. The further from root, the worse it gets. It's apparently related to how IOS devices handle floating point calcs, as referenced in these related threads:

[GitHub Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13288)
[Related (from '04)](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/archive/index.php/t-159613.html)
[Related from '07](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/archive/index.php/t-159364.html)

If working solutions have been figured out, no specific/applied examples have been given that I could find.

I've tried multiple approaches, but unsuccessfully. I don't really want to move the world instead of the player. When I've tried, I'm just not smart enough to figure it out. Moving along z isn't bad, but I can't get object rotations on y or shifting pivot points to work, no matter what groups or parent/child relations are established, or what gets copied and set from what. Matrix transforms of the mesh haven't worked well either.

This is likely a really dumb question, but is there a simpler way to just reset an origin or scene root to wherever the players current position is? Like gets done with cameras, lights, positions and rotations?

I'd really like to get this project working on IOS devices.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When you run into floating-point precision issues, you have two choices:

1. Make your world smaller. Let's say if your main character is 1000 units tall, you're "wasting" a lot of precision. You could make it 10 or 1 unit tall, and also scale everything else down so you never reach values high enough to encounter the bug.
2. You could simply nest your environment separately from your main character, and move that instead. Something like this:

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Instead of adding environment features to scene, 
// you add them to the environment group
environment = new THREE.Group();
environment.add(trees);
environment.add(streets);
environment.add(buildings);

character = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// Add environment separately from your character
scene.add(environment);
scene.add(character);

// Instead of moving your character,
// move the environment in the opposite direction
environment.position.set(-x, -y, -z);
```

This way, everything that's visible is close to `0, 0, 0`. If you need to perform rotations, use the same rule: apply it to the environment, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Hi thanks - I've tried #1, and it just magnified the problem, the jitters happened faster the smaller things got. I've been trying #2 - I set up several groups, a terrain box (ground, trees, etc), a player box (player, camera, light), and a pivot box (that holds the terrain box). The player stays at 0,0,0 and I can rotate/pivot the world ok in relation to the player after moving the terrain along z. Where I now have trouble is translating along z in relation to the direction the player is facing after being rotated... things keep sliding by sideways.

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to update the terrain to make it move opposite whatever direction the player is facing when being rotated...